# fastapi не добавляет кастомный объект в request в middleware

Tags: python, fastapi, middleware

```
@app.middleware("http")
    async def add_process_header(request: Request, call_next):
        response = await add_fields_from_jwt(request=request, call_next=call_next)
        return response


async def add_fields_from_jwt(request: Request, call_next: Callable):
    response = await call_next(request=request)
    if v := request.headers.get("authorization"):
        token = v.split()[1]
        payload = jwt.decode(jwt=token, verify=False)
        request.u = {
            "id": payload["sub"],
            "username": payload["username"],
        }
        return response
    request.u = None
    return response
```

во views в request нет атрибута u